# How to log request start in Sanic?

Tags: logging, sanic

Sanic has [access logging](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/best-practices/logging.html) but in fact it logs the *response*, that is, it fires a message when the request processing has been already completed.

But is it possible to log the request's *start*, before the user-defined middleware/handler is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to log something as *early* as possible, you can do this:

```py
from sanic.log import logger


@app.signal("http.lifecycle.request")
async def log(request):
    logger.info(f"{request.method} {request.path}")
```

See [docs on signals](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/advanced/signals.html#built-in-signals)